# view other computers on the network programatically in Python

Tags: python, networking, device

Is it possible to view other devices that are on the same network in Python (or any programming language for that matter)?

Edit: For clarification, what I'd like to do (just to start out) is to display a list of devices connected and their local IP addresses. So on my router, it'll show the info:

family_pc, 192.168.1.2
work_laptop, 192.168.1.3

I'd like to retrieve this info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly?

`nmap` is a pretty common tool for scanning networks, which seems like you want to do. There is also a [python-nmap](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap/0.1.1) package which lets you use nmap directly from within Python with ease.

Please be more detailed so we can give you a better answer, cheers.

Comment: nmap will do that for you, so perhaps look into python-nmap as I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options here.

You can run port scans over the entire network address space, but that's pretty wasteful and unfriendly.  I don't recommend it.

A nicer approach would be to query for devices using a service discovery protocol like [DNS-SD](http://www.dns-sd.org/) / [Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf) (aka [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29)).  Most Linux and Mac systems will respond, as will many network printers and other network devices.  Windows systems don't ship with a DNS-SD agent, but one can be installed.

A pure python implementation of DNS-SD is [available here](https://launchpad.net/pyzeroconf).  I have used it on Linux, MacOS, and Windows.

If you prefer a Microsoft approach, you can try the discovery features of [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), though I can't vouch for how well it works or how many systems will respond.

Comment: I think the pure python implementation is [here](https://github.com/paulsm/pyzeroconf) now.

Comment: That repo looks abandoned. Here are some newer sources:
https://github.com/jstasiak/python-zeroconf
https://github.com/wmcbrine/pyzeroconf
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zeroconf/

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind using a little third party software you could use [Netresview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/netresview.html) which works nicely on windows systems, avoid reinventing the wheel and all that. You could this kind of thing.

```
os.system('NetResView.exe /DisplayComputers 1 /RetrieveIPAddresses /stext ipfile')
my_file = open('ipfile')
for line in my_file :
    print myfile.readline()
```